# Open image link in new tab with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need some assistance with this. I am trying to make an image (ad1.jpg) link url to be opened in a new tab. How would I do this? I have tried many options to make this work. Thanks

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function($){
    $(window).load(function(){
        if(jQuery.isFunction(jQuery.fn.prettyPhoto)) {
            $.prettyPhoto.open(
                "images/ad1.jpg", // Image to be opened
                "title",    // Title of the pop-up
                "desc."     // The description
            );
            setTimeout(function() {
                $.prettyPhoto.close();
            }, 8000); // autoclose after 8 seconds
        } else {
            console.log("PrettyPhoto is not defined."); // log this message
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

Comment: Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907843/open-a-url-in-a-new-tab-using-javascript

Comment: Browser options control whether links are opened in new tabs or not.